# X axis labels tied to histogram bars instead of following separate rules

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using a histogram with x as a POSIXct value, I'm not sure how you're supposed to line the ticks up with the binsize of the graph.

Setting the tick size to the same as the binsize makes it line a bit off, but the offset adds onto each other until its no longer accurate.

```
bymonth <- ggplot() +
  scale_x_datetime("", breaks = date_breaks("60 days"), labels = date_format("%m-%y")) + 

  ...
  lots of geom_rects for background colors
  ...

  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + 

  geom_histogram(data=dat, aes(x = iso, fill = name), binwidth = 30*24*60*60, position = 'dodge')
```

I tried using `annotate()` as well as experimenting with the spacing of the tick but I think my approach here might be wrong in its own accord

This leads to a graph looking something like this

[image: image from https://i.imgur.com/73ZpG71.png]

Which is quite annoying

Comment: check the documentation for `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: can you share some of your data so we can reproduce this? its hard to help without any way of testing it ourselves

Comment: You probably want the `boundary=` or `center=` arguments to `geom_histogram`. Check the documentation to see how to use them to line up the bars.

Comment: you only need one geom_rect - make a data.frame with xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, and fill columns. You can set ymin/ymax to (-)Inf